# Android Studio Recycling Old Code After Code Changes?

Tags: android, testing, android-studio

When I am running my tests after changing some code, the previous state of the code is still being used when rerunning tests.

```
Running tests
Test running started
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.example.app.support.ConfiguredWebViewClient.<init>
at com.example.app.support.ConfiguredWebViewClientTest.testOverrideUrlLoading(ConfiguredWebViewClientTest.java:7)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:190)
at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:175)
at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:555)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1661)

Finish
```

The problem with the NoSuchMethodError above is that there IS no method by the name of testOverrideUrLoading. It was replaced by different methods. This implies that Android Studio is hanging onto old class files somehow.

Things which have no effect:

- Invalidating caches and restarting
- Cleaning the build (in Android Studio)
- Rebuilding (in Android Studio)

When I perform run `./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest`, the tests run successfully and the problem resolves in Android Studio.

I would like to know how to force this behavior while working in the IDE.

Comment: btw If you are using the new plugin version 0.9, then the task name is now `connectedAndroidTest` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22409603/cannot-run-gradlew-connectedinstrumenttest