# Cannot run ./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest

Tags: java, android, testing, gradle, android-studio

I set up a basic instrument test in Android Studio in my src/androidTest/java folder.
Now I want to run this test and everywhere I get the information to call ./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest on my OS X terminal. But that results in an error "Task 'connectedInstrumentTest' not found in project".
If I look at ./gradlew tasks the instrument task is not listed. Do I have to set anything else up in my project/build.gradle? No tutorial or docu tells me to do so, so I'm a bit confused.
Has anyone an explanation for that?
Cheers
K.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using the new plugin version 0.9, then the task name is now `connectedAndroidTest`.

You should just call `connectedCheck` though an it'll call it automatically including possibly other tests.